# Setting Environment Variables in MAMP?

Tags: php, macos, mamp

I assume that MAMP environment variables can be set in ~/.bash_profile, but it seems that setting them there does not always take effect right away. For instance, I just set a variable in my .bash_profile and have tried restarting MAMP servers, restarting MAMP itself, and even logging out of my computer and nothing seems to work. The variable is still not accessible from within my environment. Is there another way to set MAMP env vars that I'm missing or is there a cache that I need to clear?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

MAMP will load the contents of `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars` into its environment variables when starting apache.  So you can edit the file and add:

```
MY_VAR="foo"
export MY_VAR
```

Then access that variable like so:

```
echo $_ENV["MY_VAR"];
```

prints:

```
foo
```

**Update for OSX Yosemite:**

rename `envvars` to `_envvars`

See: [MAMP Pro 3.05 on Mavericks updated to Yosemite - Apache does not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139599/mamp-pro-3-05-on-mavericks-updated-to-yosemite-apache-does-not-start)

Comment: This didn't work for me on MAMP Pro 3.0.6.  I tried editing this file as well as other adjacent files `envvars_` and `envvars-std` restarting MAMP after each change.  Is there a configuration file I can dig into to see where this is being loaded?  Are there any other prerequisites for this to work?  I am looking to add a few ENVs across all of my hosts which makes this solution more appealing than the per-host one below.

Comment: @EvanMattson I don't have MAMP Pro installed, but if you can find the `apachectl` script that MAMP Pro utilizes, you can read that source to find the answer.  In mine, the path to the correct envvars file was located under a comment of `# pick up any necessary environment variables`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that file.  I'm probably just misunderstanding this.  I was checking for the presence of these using PHP, but these are probably Apache environment variables right?  The `SetEnv` method works, but like I said, I want to define variables across all of my hosts, without defining them for each one.

Comment: If the `envvars` file isn't working for you SetEnv may be what you need. But you may want to read up here on more details for that answer: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html

Comment: From a while back but still relevant to me. I looked up the `apachectl` script as @sxalexander suggested, and the path was still `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars` yet this file does not exist. Im on Mavericks, and `_envvars` and `envvars-std_` exist, but the code within both state "# This file is generated from envvars-std.in" so where is that file?? Confused as to what to edit.

Comment: @redfox05 For older versions of MAMP just create the "envvars" file and it'll work. Hope that helps :) Actually, I'll make this an answer.

Comment: @fdrv You'll have problems modifying PATH if you're running FastCGI. I have [a question an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377687/mamp-environment-variables-being-deleted-replaced-between-envvars-and-runtime) that addresses this in particular.

Comment: I tried this locally and it does work. You need to create `envvars` if it doesn't work.  
<br />
Try this to find out the right path for the file:
`$ cat /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl | grep envvars`
In my case its `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars`, which didn't exist, so I created it:
<br />
`vim /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars`.
<br />
Look in `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envars_` for a syntax example.

Comment: MAMP PRO 4.1 and Sierra, btw.

Answer (score 43):

You can also set PHP environment variables in MAMP Pro (not available in MAMP) in the `additional parameters for <VirtualHost>:` section found in the extended tab of the hosts settings panel.

[image: mamp setting php environment variable]

Screenshot is from MAMP Pro v 3.0.3

Comment: This assumes you use MAMP Pro.

Comment: you may add comments too:

    # Set local environment variable
    SetEnv APP_ENV local

Comment: How to change default libraries path? I have now /user/bin but my library in /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg so to change it I should write it like SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV /usr/local/bin ?

Answer (score 7):

You can set your environment variables in Apache configuration...

```
/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf

SetEnv MY_VAR theValue
SetEnv ANOTHER thisIsTheValue
```

Comment: This is the only way it works for me - in MAMP 4 (the non-pro) version

Answer (score 3):

MAMP is looking for "/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars", if the file doesn't, simply create it and add your environment variables.

Comment: Also use: `echo 'export KEY=VALUE' >> /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about a local server?

I've noticed, if you look at the processes that apache can have multiple instance running that you might need to check.  If they are, quit out of them individually, as the restart won't take the new changes until all instances are restarted.  Something to try.

Answer (score 0):

If you still can't get your environment variables:

you may need to edit your **real** httpd.conf in

> ~/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/

instead of

> /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/

Also you may need to use **getenv()** instead of **$_ENV**

Answer (score 0):

But it doesn't work with El Capitan. You should disable [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection).

[original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33001009/2309309)