# Unable to install Magento 1.9 on MAMP

Tags: magento

When attempting to visit my new Magento instance for the first time I recieve the following error:

```
[05-Jan-2015 13:28:46 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getModelInstance() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/magento/app/Mage.php on line 463
[05-Jan-2015 13:28:46 America/Chicago] PHP Stack trace:
[05-Jan-2015 13:28:46 America/Chicago] PHP   1. {main}() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/magento/index.php:0
[05-Jan-2015 13:28:46 America/Chicago] PHP   2. Mage::run($code = *uninitialized*, $type = *uninitialized*, $options = *uninitialized*) /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/magento/index.php:87
[05-Jan-2015 13:28:46 America/Chicago] PHP   3. Mage::printException($e = *uninitialized*, $extra = *uninitialized*) /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/magento/app/Mage.php:702
[05-Jan-2015 13:28:46 America/Chicago] PHP   4. Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore($id = *uninitialized*) /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/magento/app/Mage.php:920
[05-Jan-2015 13:28:46 America/Chicago] PHP   5. Mage_Core_Model_App->_getDefaultStore() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:815
[05-Jan-2015 13:28:46 America/Chicago] PHP   6. Mage::getModel($modelClass = *uninitialized*, $arguments = *uninitialized*) /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:900
```

I'm using the latest MAMP PRO with PHP 5.4.34. The virtual host resolves and is configured properly, pointing to /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/magento which is where index.php, install.php, etc, are located.

I am attempting to use the sample database and have properly populated the database, the media directory, and the skin directory. I've ensured all file ownership and permissions are correct including removing any additional Mac OS downloaded file security related flags.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that your server is passing in an incorrect value `*uninitialized*` for `$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']` and `$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']`.

You can test this by opening the **index.php** file in the Magento root, going down to the bottom and replacing this:

```
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

With this:

```
Mage::run('base', 'store');
```

If you look above it, Magento is using the `$_SERVER` variable to determine which code/type to run.

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';
```

This is essentially used for multi-site Magento environments so Magento can switch stores based on the domain/server variables.

If the above test I've provided fixes the issue, look into why your server is returning `*uninitialized*` for the `$_SERVER` variables, instead of PHP determining they are not set.

---

You can also try setting the Magento environmental variables within the MAMP Pro interface which may fix the issue.  If you use this solution, you can revert any modifications made to your index.php file (I'd recommend not making any permanent changes to it in the first place).

Go to Hosts, select the server you are running Magento on the left, and click **Extended** on the right.

In the **Additional Parameters** for , enter the following:

```
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "base" # put here your website or store code
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "website" # put here 'website' or 'store'
```

[image: MAMP Pro v 3.0.3]

Tip provided per [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22773045/1332068).

Comment: I'm using the default files from the Magento 1.9 archive. There are no changes to any files.

Comment: Ok?  Did you try any of the solutions I've provided?

Comment: Tried the MAMP stuff, no go

Comment: Well it's a good thing that I also provided ways to debug and find the cause (editing the index).  If you're not going to to leverage all the information I spent the time to provide to you, then don't expect to come to a resolution, or get closer to solving your issue.

Comment: Well since the stuff you posted didn't work, I'm not sure what else you want from me?

Comment: I'm telling you, the problem is the '*uninitialized*' value being passed into the Magento core.  Determine why it's doing that and you'll solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is mostly due to Folder Permissions of the magento. Try to change the folder permissions to `777` by using `chmod 777 -R` and once  it works fine, then you can revert it back to `775` by using `chmod 775 -R`

Comment: As indicated in the original post, permissions, ownership, and extended flags are already in the proper state.