# can not modify PATH with putenv() running MAMP / PHP 5.6.1 / Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: php, path, environment-variables, mamp, osx-elcapitan

Config:
MAMP Pro
PHP 5.6.1
Mac OS X El Capitan

I need to add `/user/local/bin` to the system paths php can access

I've tried to use putenv()

but it seems like I can't change the value of environment variable PATH in php using putenv()

`putenv('PATH=' . '/user/local/bin' . PATH_SEPARATOR . getenv('PATH') );`

does not change the value

this works with other variables

PATH seems to be protected and I can not figure out where I can unprotect it - php ini settings do not seem to have anything regarding non-safe mode env vars.

does that ring a bel with anyone?

thanks

Comment: It's working as you would expect on my end. You understand that the change only affects the execution of the current script and doesn't export the new variable globally, right? (FWIW, I haven't updated to El Capitan yet)

Comment: How are you checking your change? I can do a `putenv` of `PATH` that shows up fine with `echo getenv('PATH');` afterwards in the version of PHP that comes with El Capitan, but I've not got MAMP Pro...

Answer (score 0):

Possibly protected by the new "rootless" or SIP(System Integrity Protection). I do not recommend disabling this feature unless you really know what you are doing, but disabling it could solve your problem.

[More Info Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) (wikipedia page)
and how to [Disable It Here](http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/) (OS X daily)