# MAMP: Environment variables being deleted/replaced between envvars and runtime

Tags: php, apache, path, environment-variables, mamp

Using MAMP + MAMP Pro 3.5 for local development. Using the `envvars` file, I'm supplying my own PATH, that is different from the PATH for any other user or purpose. Let's pretend it's `/my/unique/custom/path`.

I put the following file on my local development site:

```
<ol>
    <li><?php print $_SERVER['PATH']; ?></li>
    <li><?php print $_ENV['PATH']; ?></li>
    <li><?php print exec('echo $PATH'); ?></li>
</ol>
```

And this is the result:

> 1. /my/unique/custom/path
> 2. /my/unique/custom/path
> 3. /usr/gnu/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:.

So PHP sees that the PATH environment variable is supposed to be mine, but somehow it's not the one actually used to run commands.

What could be causing this? Apparently that #3 PATH is the default path for bash, if you don't set one, I think? What could be causing it to get either deleted or never set, given that PHP sees it correctly?

**UPDATE 1:**

Running `print_r(shell_exec('env'))` gets me this and nothing more:

```
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x0
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=4
PWD=/path/to/website/files
SHLVL=1
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=200
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Pretty bare. Seems like that $_ variable is a big clue, but I don't yet know to what.

**UPDATE 2:**

Okay, so it ends up that a bare environment is normal. This is why you set environment variables in `envvars` in the first place. But `envvars` is clearly working, or else that path wouldn't show up in `$_SERVER`. So something is happening between the time `envvars` is run and the time I run my own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit here ended up being FastCGI. By default, it clears all environment variables from your PHP scripts. Security feature, I guess.

With MAMP, there's not a way to turn that `clear_env` setting off globally. But if you edit the appropriate `/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/phpX.Y.Z.fcgi` file, you can add a line like so:

```
export PATH='/my/unique/custom/path'
```

...and you're in business.

Make sure you add that line *above* the last line already in the file that begins with `exec`.